# How to define key in DynamoDB table if most of the columns make a unique item

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DDB item which looks like this

```
Attribute 1  

Attribute 2

Attribute 3

Attribute 4

Attribute 5

Attribute 6

Attribute 7

Attribute 8

Attribute 9

Attribute 10

Attribute 11
```

Attributes 1 - 9 makes an unique item in my table. 
My most of the queries will start with Attributes 1-3

```
I was thinking of 

Hash Key = Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3

Range Key = Attribute3_Attribute4_Attribute5_Attribute6_Attribute7_Attribute8
```

But then the it looks ugly when i implement. Too much repetition of same attributes in different classes with Converters for both hash and range key. I need all columns to make further GSIs on Attribute 3,5 &7.

```
2nd option 
Hash Key = Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3

Range Key = UUID
```

In 2nd option i can query based on hash keys and add GSI for others queries.

```
3rd option 
Hash Key = UUID

Range Key = No range key
```

Add a column for composite attribute Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3 and build GSI on all queries.

What is the best practices in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is the have the Hash key composed in this way:

```
Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3
```

No need for sort key if you don't use it. Just add other attributes as regular columns. Whenever needed (based on your queries), you can add additional GSI on those attributes or create a compound one of any size.

---

If `Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3` is not unique, then use a `uuid` as hash key and set GSI on all others.

Comment: Thanks for answering! 
Yes, i am going with same solution you mentioned, 
UUID as hash key
 Using composite GSI with  GSI Hash Key = Attribute1_Attribute2_Attribute3

& GSI Range Key = Attribute3_Attribute4_Attribute5_Attribute6_Attribute7_Attribute8
But now how do i enforce uniqueness based on GSI hash and range.
I need to make sure that there is only single item with GSI Hash + GSI range.